# perf (linux performance tool) : low max Children consumption per symbol

Tags: linux, perf

I develop a C++ program on Linux Ubuntu. In order to improve its performance, I attach perf to the process using
`sudo perf record -g -p <pid>`. Then I stop it (CTRL-C) and watch the report
`sudo perf report`

The max Children percentage is only at 17.48% !

I don't understand why there is no symbol with a higher percentage.
If my idea about perf is correct, I should find the symbol of the main function with a Children measure at 100%. (each collected events has the main symbol at its top).

In the past I used perf on a different computer and that was roughly the case (I remember having the top symbols with Children at 99.xx %)

Is it possible that perf do not capture the stack deep enough ? Is there a way to make it work as intended ?

Comment: Are all the samples of userspace? The default stack deepth is limited by '/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_max_stack' (default 127).